# Collections.sort() doesn't work for custom Objects

Tags: java, sorting, object, collections

I'm trying to sort my List but this one doesn't work. Method collections.sort() does nothing.

```
public boolean schedule(){
    List<Task> keys = new ArrayList<Task>(g.tasks.keySet());
    for(int i = 0; i<keys.size();i++){
        System.out.println(keys.get(i).getSize());
    }
    Collections.sort(keys);
    for(int i = 0; i<keys.size();i++){
        System.out.println(keys.get(i).getSize());
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is my compareTo() method in Task class:

```
public int compareTo(Task t1) {
    Integer csize = new Integer(t1.size);
    int cmp = csize.compareTo(t1.size);

    return cmp;
}
```

What is wrong in this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> collections.sort doesn't work for custom objects

Sure it does, but it won't in your case because your compareTo method is broken. You're comparing t1's size to itself, not to the size of `this`

You've got:

```
public int compareTo(Task t1) {
    Integer csize = new Integer(t1.size);  // get t1's size
    int cmp = csize.compareTo(t1.size);  // ???? compare with t1's size ???

    return cmp;
}
```

You need to change it to something like:

```
public int compareTo(Task t1) {
    return Integer.compare(this.size, t1.size);
}
```

So now you're comparing the size of the parameter with the size of the current object.

Comment: Thank you very much, one more tiny question. How can I sort it from the lowest to the highest becouse now is the opposite

Comment: @Buszman: Oh it's trivial -- and I bet if you guess, you can figure it out in seconds -- so, what do you think?

Comment: @Buszman: Hint -- you only need to slightly change my one line of code.

Comment: reverse comparing objects i suppose

Comment: @Buszman: Yup! And the other option is to do, `Collections.sort(keys, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Don't know why I didn't notice it earlier :P

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in `compareTo` that has been pointed out in the accepted answer. I am supplying an additional answer only to provide a different idiom you might consider for defining natural order of a class:

```
class Task implements Comparable<Task> {
    private static final Comparator<Task> ORDER = Comparator
        .comparingInt(Task::getSize)
        .reversed()
        .thenComparing(Task::getPriority);

    public int compareTo(Task other) {
        return ORDER.compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

The potential advantage of this delegation idiom is that on casual reading of a traditional `compareTo` implementation it's easy to miss things such as the order of arguments reversing the comparison. The declaration makes it very explicit. This also means that you have all the features of `Comparator` available (e.g. deciding if nulls are first or last).

Comment: Nice answer 1+!

Answer (score 0):

Already answer was posted by @HoverCraft.
In addition to that

```
//For ASC
public int compareTo(Task t1) {
   return (this.size - t1.size);
}
//For DESC
public int compareTo(Task t1) {
   return (t1.size - this.size);
}
```